# iLovePDF Library - Fatal error: Class 'Ilovepdf' not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I was trying to compress PDF. I try my best to find out some library that can be free too for some limited purpose. I found out [iLovePDF Library](https://github.com/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php).

I try to get it done using composer and without composer too But not find any way to resolve it.

**My Code:**

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
// require_once('vendor/ilovepdf/init.php');
$ilovepdf = new Ilovepdf('project_public_key','secret_key');
$myTask = $ilovepdf->newTask('compress');
$file1 = $myTask->addFile('file1.pdf');
$myTask->execute();
$myTask->download();
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Ilovepdf' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP Doc\E15\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP Doc\E15\index.php on line 11

Comment: `require_once('vendor/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php/init.php');use Ilovepdf\PdfaTask;
`
add these lines too

Comment: It also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You.

I resolved it by adding below line at the top of index.php

```
namespace Ilovepdf;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use namespaces:

```
$ilovepdf = new \Ilovepdf\Ilovepdf('project_public_key','secret_key');
```

Or:

```
use \Ilovepdf\Ilovepdf;
$ilovepdf = new Ilovepdf('project_public_key','secret_key');
```